# Cross platform sprite creation for game developement

Tags: open-source, game-development, animation

Is there any open source cross platform sprite creation for game development process where I can stitch multiple images into a single animated sprite with adjustable row and columns?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, could you please post an image or drawing showing what the result would look like?

Comment: [Sample sprite](https://cdn.codeandweb.com/blog/2013/05/16/uikit-animations-with-texturepacker/spritesheet.png).Here I can upload multiple images and then it can merge into single sprite.